# how to use ng.core.HostListener and ng.core.HostBinding in custom directive in ES5 flavor of Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a custom directive in ES5, that needs to take action each time the host element is clicked, and based on a validation either accepts the click, or stops the event's propagation. In fact, I'm trying to create this delete functionality:

```
 <button 
        md-icon-button 
        confirmClick="Are you sure?" 
        (click)="delete()">
            <md-icon>delete</md-icon>
    </button
```

I'm stuck at how to use `ng.core.HostListener` in ES5. Here's my custom directive's code:

```
var confirmClick = ng.core.Directive({
        selector: '[confirmClick]'
    }).Class({
        constructor: function() {
            console.log('this line is printed out, so things are OK');
        }
    });
```

How should I bind to the host element's click event in Angular 2 ES5 custom directive? and how to stop that event?

Answer (score 1):

There is special property `host` that you can use like:

```
var confirmClick = ng.core.Directive({
    selector: '[confirmClick]',
    host: {
      '(click)': 'onClick($event)',
    }
  }).Class({
    constructor: function() {
        console.log('this line is printed out, so things are OK');
    },
    onClick() {

    }
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/TdoXCMYvGUn8vjUZCuDR?p=preview)**

Another way is setting `propMetadata` property to constructor function like:

```
function ConfirmClass() {}

ConfirmClass.propMetadata = {
  onClick: [new ng.core.HostListener('click'), ['$event']]
};

var confirmClick = ng.core.Directive({
    selector: '[confirmClick]'
  }).Class({
      constructor: ConfirmClass,
      onClick: function() {
        alert(3)
      }
  });
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0Uw2K6Ol6gZAHeLQExDy?p=preview)**

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/4.1.0-rc.0/aio/content/examples/cb-ts-to-js/js/src

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var directive = ng.core.Directive({
    selector: '[directiveAttribute]',
    host: {
        '(click)': 'doSomething($event)'
    }
}).Class({
    constructor: function() {
    },
    doSomething: function(event) {

    }
});
```

To understand it more, read [*TypeScript to JavaScript*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#host-binding) from official angular documents.

Comment: Ok great, please clean comments as I did.